# How to convert time date from JSON to human readable?

Tags: php, arrays, json

Kindly help me with converting JSON time data to 12 hrs human readable time in PHP.

Data I got as time from JSON is: 1380, 1395 and so on
Real time corresponding to JSON time data is as follows.
    For 1380 is 11.00PM
    For 1395 is 11.15PM

Now kindly tell me how to convert (1380, 1395, etc) into human readable time 12hrs in PHP

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This isn't a json time, there's no such thing as a standard json time.... this is just some arbitrary format that somebody has chosen to use

Comment: However, without knowing how 1380 equates to 11:00pm then it's pretty difficult for anybody to answer.... but it looks like number of minutes after midnight (00:00)

Comment: @markBaker 1440 minutes = 24 hours, so 1380 minutes is 23 hours (11PM)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like 1380 is number of minutes for that day.

You can use [gmdate()](http://php.net/gmdate). First convert the minutes into seconds (by multiplying by 60) and then use it in gmdate function.

```
echo gmdate("h:i A", 1380*60);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this value is simply the number of minutes since midnight:

```
$value = 1395;
$hours = floor($value / 60);
$minutes = $value - ($hours * 60);

$time = $hours . ':' . $minutes;
```

Though some clarification on what happens on daylight savings days would be useful